# how to get exact height of body of the webbrowser window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to get exact height of the body of webbrowser window. I tried innerHeight, clientHeight all other solutions which I get while googling. but none of them give exact height. I had to adjust the height by subtracting some value from the height provided by these functions?? How can get out of this problem. I think I'm missing some thing. please help.

Thanks

Comment: Will jQuery solution work for you?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Some browsers report the window height <strike>incorrectly</strike> differently - particularly mobile browsers, which have a different viewport concept. I sometimes use a function to check several different values, returning whichever is the greatest. For example

```
function documentHeight() {
    return Math.max(
        window.innerHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.clientHeight
    );
}
```

**Edit:** I just looked at how jQuery does it and it does indeed use Math.max and a series of properties - however the list it checks is slightly different to those in my example above, and since I usually trust the jQuery team to be better at this stuff than I am; here is the non-jQuery jQuery solution (if that makes any sense):

```
function documentHeight() {
    return Math.max(
        document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        document.body.scrollHeight,
        document.documentElement.scrollHeight,
        document.body.offsetHeight,
        document.documentElement.offsetHeight
    );
}
```

Comment: plus 1 for easy and *"non-JQuery jQuery solution"*, ha

Comment: :) Thanks. Bit old now perhaps, but maybe still valid/useful? Don't tend to bother much about browser/screen pixel dimensions these days - all fluid, stretchy and "responsive" :| More CSS3 and media queries than JavaScript/jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

You can use Jquery to achieve this...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    browserWindowheight = $(window).height();
    alert(browserWindowheight);
});
```

Comment: He never said he was using jquery.

Comment: I mentioned that he has to use jquery... then why downvoting..?

Comment: where does he say he doesn't want to use jquery?

Comment: @nunespascal He hasn't mentioned that he doesn't need jQuery. And instead of downvoting why don't you put your efforts in answer?

Comment: @nunespascal reply here how are you sure that he doesn't want a Jquery solution...???? i can't see any kind of phrase in his question that he doesn't want to use Jquery??? Its really bad that you are missusing your reputation of downvoting.

Comment: @nunespascal I think jQuery is a valid approach to use. Especially since the OP is having problems getting a consistent result, and that's what jQuery delivers in this case.

Comment: @nunepascal I deleted my answer after you bit my head off - what's with the aggro? Not like jQuery much?

Comment: I agree jquery is a good approach. I am just saying the solutions are incomplete without telling the user that he should use jquery.

Comment: @nunespascal The first thing this solution says is "You can use Jquery to achieve this".

Comment: Can't you see in my answer that I have written **You can use Jquery to achieve this...**

Comment: @nunespascal You are misusing your reputation and discouraging the people who really give answers. THIS IS NOT THE WAY

Comment: You changed your answer later Subhajit. It was not there when I downvoted it.

Comment: You missed it or not noticed, its was there from bigining mate... :)
From next time before downvoting check the answer totally and ready each word..

Comment: hi guys! I don't have problem in using jquery. That's why I didn't mention it. Sorry for that. I just want the solution to my problem.

Comment: @nunespascal Or give a right answer instead of examining other

Comment: @newprogress okay then just ignore the comments and check the solution let us know whether it helped it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using:

```
window.outerHeight (this is for IE9 and other modern browser's height)
```

For Internet Explorer with backward-compatibility mode, use

```
document.body.offsetHeight
```

And also, Internet Explorer (standards mode, document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat'):

```
document.documentElement.offsetHeight
```

Have a look at the following for more information:

- http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm
- http://everyday-tech.blogspot.com.au/2009/07/js-calculate-browser-window-height.html