# Detecting if vertical scroll is visible

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code. How to do the same thing but using pure JavaScript? I want to detect if the scrollbar is visible.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if body height is higher than window height :)
    if ($("body").height() > $(window).height()) {
        alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
    }

});
```

I had tried to do this way and it didn't work

```
if(document.body.height > window.height){
  alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?  What problem does it solve?

Comment: I Want to implement a function when the scroll in the body appears after the user resizes the window because it misaligns some canvas elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
if(document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight){
  alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
}
```

See snippet for example:

```js
if(document.body.scrollHeight > window.innerHeight){
  alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
}
```

```html
<div style="height:1000px"></div>
```

Related: [How to get height of entire document with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1145850/how-to-get-height-of-entire-document-with-javascript) and [how to get exact height of body of the webbrowser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11077475/how-to-get-exact-height-of-body-of-the-webbrowser-window).

Answer (score 0):

You can insert div tag in your body tag and set div height and overflow auto.see below sample code.

```
<body>
   <div id="innerscroll" style="width: 100px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">* content</div>
</body>
```

Add script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Check if body height is higher than window height :)
    if ($("#innerscroll").get(0).scrollHeight > $(window).height()) {
        alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
    }
});
```

Its working.

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

```
if(document.body.scrollHeight > window.height){
  alert("Vertical Scrollbar! D:");
}
```